# How to center in column multiple flex-boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm studying CSS, so it might be a stupid question. I can't figure out why even though I have
`flex-flow: column;` items are in a row.

I created a flex container for the whole body. Then some children flex div. The parent container should put children in column. Then I wanted to use children css properties to better manage their content. As you can see from my codepen there are 6 cards a video and 3 cards. In theory the video should be placed under the 6 cards and above the others 3 cards because they are contained in 3 different `div`, where did I go wrong?

CodePen link:

https://codepen.io/vujinbaku/pen/MWmgdvq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 43 you have an opening div tag instead of closing div tag. Also in line 50 you forgot to close the div tag after h3.

Comment: I can't believe it.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect, you'll see that majority of the code lies under a `<div class="part>`. It is because you have unclosed div tags. Do the following steps.

1. In `line: 29`, close `<div>` tag by replacing `<div>` with `</div>`.
2. In `line: 43`, close `<div>` tag by replacing `<div>` with `</div>`.

While you are in the process of learning web development, I'd suggest you to explore best practices like sectioning your code. This helps in debugging effectively.